# snmp - timeout when connecting master and agent

Tags: linux, ubuntu, snmp

Everytime that I run a command to interact the manager(server) to the agent(client) I get 'snmpget: Timeout'. this happens both ways
both are configured to accept connection from remote hosts.
I'm new to snmp. I may have forget to do something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNMP protocol uses specific ports (161 & 162 )for communications.

161 for snmpget type of commands and 162 for traps.

Ensure that these two ports are open on both hosts

Comment: Yes, both ports are open but still everytime that I execute a snmp command. I get no flags. Like
'snmpget: timeout'
'snmpusm: '
Its hard because I didnt receive any flag or warning.

Comment: Troubleshooting steps                                                                                                     1)Verify that snmp configuration is completely done by looking the snmpd.conf file                                                                                2)Verify snmpd process is running   /etc/init.d/snmpd status                                                            3)All the required MIB files are present in the system. This command gives the location where MIB files are looked by snmpd process :     net-snmp-config --default-mibdirs

Comment: Actually shomil I found out that one of my port is in the state of filtering. Now I have the connections . thanks for the help. Hope to hear from you more if I have another question about this topic